# Sending LINQ Query to Entity Framework as string

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

How I can send a linq query as string to Entity Framework for example:

```
from s in students select s
```

I want to compile this in oracle and sql server

Comment: Entity Sql is designed for this sort of thing, linq to entities would mean you have to execute dynamic code, which is nasty to say the least.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might want to have a look at [Entity SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387145.aspx).
Here is an example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738684.aspx

Another possibility is [Dynamic LINQ](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx).

Comment: Entity Sql gets string command but it is not linq query and it has kind of sql server structure howover I want to compile this in orcal and sql.

Comment: Entity SQL is just as database-independent as normal LINQ, i.e. it gets translated to your Database's native query language, too. However, you can also have a look at Dynamic LINQ (see edit of my answer).

Answer (score 0):

i use Dynamic Linq to dynamically construct linq queries at run time

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

Comment: it seems that it is limited to condition of query but I want to construct the whole of query